# How to get similart Geomagic two stl file deviation in free Cloudcompare software?

Tags: computer-engineering

I need to compare two STL (Dental model Scanned) files and find the deviation between their points, SO this two STL files have different boundary, so i already used the [GEOMAGIC Control software](https://www.3dsystems.com/software/geomagic-control-x) for comparing STL files, one sample output file would be like this:
[image]

I found these two like:

[Are there any open source alternatives for geomagic?](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Are_there_any_open_source_alternatives_for_geomagic)

[How to compare/quantify (populate) two .stl models having shape difference to see result as color stl file and bar telling plus and minus changes?](https://www.researchgate.net/post/how_to_compare_quantify_populate_two_stl_models_having_shape_difference_to_see_result_as_color_stl_file_and_bar_telling_plus_and_minus_changes)

useful for finding free alternative software for Geomagic, So i installed the [Cloudcompare](http://www.danielgm.net/cc/) in my Linux OS, and aligned two stl file  and used the ***compute cloud/mesh distance*** icon and get this output picture of stl which shown geomagic output above:

[image]

So in the **CloudCompare** output i have 1 aria which i don't want to be.
How could i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason, i must use other ***stl*** as references and the out put have this kind:
[image]